# Нужно объединить/сининимизировать метки [decorator] и [декоратор]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Нужно объединить/сининимизировать метки [decorator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decorator) и [декоратор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), основная - `декоратор`

- [декоратор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) - 87 вопросов
- [decorator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decorator) - 51 вопрос

Comment: А ещё `список` и `list`.

Comment: @VladimirChistov для этого отдельный вопрос создайте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил

[decorator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decorator) → [декоратор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)